# Telegraf [inputs.disk] on Windows: device not ready error

Tags: windows, telegraf

We monitor our Windows 7 nodes with [Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/). 4 machines in total, but the error exists only on 1 of them.

telegraf.conf:

```
[inputs.disk]
mount_points = ["C:"]
```

Running telegraf produces the following error in log file:

> ERROR in input [inputs.disk]: error getting disk usage info: The device is not ready.

Running telegraf with `--test` and `--debug` flags does not provide any further information.

```
$ C:\opt\telegraf\telegraf.exe --config C:\opt\telegraf\telegraf.conf --test --debug --input-filter disk
* Plugin: inputs.disk, Collection 1
```

The disk itself is working - the machine is connected as Jenkins slave and we run tests there. I can also open a window with disk properties and can see and click everything through. As I said this error is only on 1 of 4 machines.

Any pointers how can this be debugged further?